# jQuery .find() or .next() for traversal?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have some code where I'm using jQuery to execute a function on a specific item in a loop, since it has to show many of the same on a page.

ultimately I'm trying to show the second section on click of the anchor tag, and hide the first one.  Then I'll reverse the process for the click of the button inside the second section.

We've been using jQuery things like .next(), .find(),.closest() and .prev() for traversal from an element.target (click) to manipulate specific containers and not affect any other containers on the page that share the same selectors.

So, for this code, I'm getting it wrong so far, and can't quite figure out the traversal puzzle for this one.

```
        <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: FilteredThings, as: 'Thing' }">
            <li>
                <header>
                    <a class="focus-element-flag" data-bind="click: $parent.ShowSection1hideSection2">
                        <div>
                            <div></div>
                            <div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div><label></label></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </header>
                <section id="section1" class="currently-shown">
                     //some content
                </section>
                <section id="section2" class="currently-hidden">
                    <div>
                        <button class="closeButton" data-bind="click: $parent.ShowSection1hideSection2">
                            <span>Close</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <table>
                       //some content
                    </table>
                </section>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Then I have a function similar to this:

```
vm.ShowSection1hideSection2 = function (Event) {
    $(Event.target).find(".currently-shown").css('display', 'none');
    $(Event.target).find(".currently-hidden").css('display', 'block');
}
```

Now I know this function is incorrect, but it is an example of what I'm trying to do either using .next(), .find(), .siblings(), etc.

I left all of the html tags inside the anchor tag to show that the possibility of multiple "targets" is possible, but as look as they all look for the right selector using jQuery, I'm good to go.

Anyone have any advice on which combination of jQuery to use in my function?  Thank you in advance.  I've been researching and doing some trail and error for a few hours now.

Comment: The problem is probably that you don't know exactly what your specs are, or at least they're not coming along to me precisely enough. You should try to extend the code into a [mcve], be precise about what the code should be doing and how your current code is failing to do so. In addition, please explain why you're mixing jQuery and an MVVM framework like this: usually with an MV* framework you have the view represent some kind of (view)model and place the show/hide logic in there...

Comment: Maybe "usually" in your experience.  There's nothing wrong with using jQuery to keep some functionality on the front end.  This application uses knockout.js for most of it's functionality inside the VM.  As you can see in my function name, it's in the vm.  However, none of this has anything to do with my jQuery question.  I believe I've supplied adequate code and text to convey my question.

Comment: 't was merely meant as a side note, the main problem I had when trying to help you was that it's hard to imagine the full thing you're aiming for because the code in the post isn't enough to reproduce an accurate scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Knockout here is my suggestion to take advantage of knockout power and keep your items separate 

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/97/

```
 var MainViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        //Assuming this is your data
        var arrOfObj = [{name:'Name 1',value:'value 1'},
                        {name:'Name 2',value:'value 2'},
                        {name:'Name 3',value:'value 3'}];
        //For each obj you create a new instance of ItemViewModel 
       self.FilteredThings = ko.observableArray($.map(arrOfObj, function (item) {
         return new ItemViewModel(item);
        }));
    }
      var ItemViewModel = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.Name = ko.observable(data.name);
        self.Value = ko.observable(data.value);
        self.ShowSection1 = ko.observable(true);
        self.ShowSection2 = ko.observable(false);
        self.ShowSection1hideSection2 = function (){
          // here your logic to show or hide different section  
            self.ShowSection1(!self.ShowSection1());
            self.ShowSection2(!self.ShowSection2());
        }
    }
    ko.applyBindings(MainViewModel);
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, great alternative to what I was trying.